# PHP memory usage with Mongo Driver

Tags: php, mongodb, memory

I tested retrieving 150 documents, each with an array of 2000 records.
This is the memory usage:

```
Memory after collection: 1584
Memory after findOne: 530936
Memory after find: 81798960
```

So findOne uses around 0.5MB, while finding 150 documents uses 78MB.

Is it normal to have such high memory usage? Or is my document object too huge? I'm just storing like four characters in each of the 2000 records.

Code used for the test:

```
<?php
    $old = memory_get_usage();
    $collection = $mongo->getMongoCollection($this->Mb);
    $new = memory_get_usage();
    echo "Memory after collection: " . ($new - $old) . "<br>";

    $old = memory_get_usage();
    $arr = $collection->findOne(array('capture' => '1367208145'));
    $new = memory_get_usage();
    echo "Memory after findOne: " . ($new - $old) . "<br>";

    $old = memory_get_usage();
    $cursor = $collection->find();
    $arr = iterator_to_array($cursor);
    $new = memory_get_usage();
    echo "Memory after find: " . ($new - $old) . "<br>";
?>
```

Comment: Nope that's not normal, what PHP Driver version is this? However if each doc has an array of 2000 documents then maybe, I would try using 'sizeof(bson_encode())' on one document to see how big it really is and then do some calcs

Comment: That seems weird indeed. Which driver version are you using?
iterator_to_array() is fairly expensive operation as it has to fetch all the data and build all the arrays before returning, so in general you should be iterating over the cursor instead.

Comment: Php Mongo driver v1.3.5. I was trying to do export by fetching through Php. But then I realised there's a utility mongoexport that does it much much faster and better. I guess we shouldn't be using Php to do too much fetching.

Comment: i am experiencing same problems with the mongodb cursor, do you have any new insights on the memory usage problem ?